# Terraform module output not resolving for input variables in other module

Tags: azure, terraform

#### Terraform Version

```
Terraform v0.11.11
+ provider.azurerm v1.21.0
```

#### Terraform Configuration Files

I have left many required fields for brevity (all other config worked before I added the connection strings).

```
# modules/function/main.tf

variable "conn-value" {}
locals {
  conn = "${map("name", "mydb", "value", "${var.conn-value}", "type", "SQLAzure")}"
}
resource "azurerm_function_app" "functions" {
  connection_string = "${list(local.conn)}"
  # ...
}

# modules/db/main.tf

# ... other variables declared

resource "azurerm_sql_server" "server" {
  # ...
}

output "connection-string" {
  value = "Server=tcp:${azurerm_sql_server.server.fully_qualified_domain_name},1433;Initial Catalog=${var.catalog};Persist Security Info=False;User ID=${var.login};Password=${var.login-password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=200;"
}

# main.tf

module "my_db" {
  source = "modules/db"
}

module "my_app" {
  source = "modules/function"
  conn-value = "${module.my_db.connection-string}"
  # ...
}
```

#### Expected Behavior on `terraform plan`

The `module.my_db.connection-string` output resolves to a string when passed to the `my_app` `conn-value` variable and is able to be used in the map/list passed to the `azurerm_function_app.functions.connection_string` variable.

#### Actual Behavior on `terraform plan`

I get this error:

```
module.my_app.azurerm_function_app.functions: connection_string: should be a list
```

If I replace `"${var.conn-value}"` in the `modules/function/main.tf` `locals` with just a string, it works.

#### Update

In response to to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54498947/terraform-module-output-not-resolving-for-input-variables-in-other-module?noredirect=1#comment95808023_54498947), I updated the script above with the connection string construction.

Comment: You should really show how you are building the `connection-string` output here considering that is what your error is complaining about.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR it's complaining about `local.conn` technically, but I'll add it.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I added the `connection-string` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16582#issuecomment-342570913) that references the problem I am having (I found the issue through this [gist comment](https://gist.github.com/brikis98/f3fe2ae06f996b40b55eebcb74ed9a9e#gistcomment-2374185)). This describes the problem exactly:

> Assigning values to nested blocks is not supported, but appears to work in certain cases due to a number of coincidences...

This limitation is in <= v0.11, but is apparently [fixed](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/7034#issuecomment-433511035) in v0.12 with the `dynamic` block.